# unable to call onchange function on windows load

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
window.onload = function (){
    $("#work_sanctioned_year").change();
};
    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#work_sanctioned_year").change();
}); 
    
    $("#work-sanctioned-year").change(function(){
        var work_sanctioned_year = $(this).val();
        alert(work_sanctioned_year);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'get_data.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {work_sanctioned_year:work_sanctioned_year},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    
                    success:function(response){
                    FusionCharts.ready();
                    }
        });
        FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var dataChart = new FusionCharts({
      "type": "overlappedBar2d",
      "renderAt": "chart-5",
      "width": '100%',
      "height": '400',
      "dataFormat": "json",
      "dataSource": {
        "chart": {
          "caption": "Major League Baseball - Season Rankings",
          "subCaption": "Teams in the Lead",
          "xAxisName": "Team",
          "yAxisName": "Position",
          "theme": "fusion",
          "showValues": "0"
        },
        "categories": [{
            "labelFontSize": "13",
          "category": [{
            "label": "Boston Red Sox"
          }, {
            "label": "New York Yankees"
          }, {
            "label": "Tampa Bay Rays"
          }, {
            "label": "Toronto Blue Jays"
          }, {
            "label": "Baltimore Orioles"
          }, {
            "label": "Cleveland Indians"
          }, {
            "label": "Detroit Tigers"
          }, {
            "label": "Minnesota Twins"
          }, {
            "label": "Chicago White Sox"
          }, {
            "label": "Kansas City Royals"
          }, {
            "label": "Cleveland Indians"
          }, {
            "label": "Detroit Tigers"
          }, {
            "label": "Minnesota Twins"
          }, {
            "label": "Chicago White Sox"
          }]
        }],
        "dataset": [{
          "seriesname": "Matches",
          "data": [{
            "value": parseInt(document.getElementById("work_sanctioned").value)-4650
          }, {
            "value": "84"
          }, {
            "value": "86"
          }, {
            "value": "86"
          }, {
            "value": "85"
          }, {
            "value": "85"
          }, {
            "value": "88"
          }, {
            "value": "83"
          }, {
            "value": "86"
          }, {
            "value": "86"
          }, {
            "value": "85"
          }, {
            "value": "88"
          }, {
            "value": "83"
          }, {
            "value": "86"
          }]
        }, {
          "seriesname": "Wins",
          "data": [{
            "value": "57"
          }, {
            "value": "54"
          }, {
            "value": "42"
          }, {
            "value": "39"
          }, {
            "value": "24"
          }, {
            "value": "46"
          }, {
            "value": "38"
          }, {
            "value": "35"
          }, {
            "value": "29"
          }, {
            "value": "25"
          }, {
            "value": "46"
          }, {
            "value": "38"
          }, {
            "value": "35"
          }, {
            "value": "29"
          }, {
            "value": "25"
          }]
        }]
      }
    })
    .render();
});

    });
```

when m selecting something from the dropdown its working. but when what m trying to do is call the function with the first value by default.I have tried both window.onload method and .ready function individually but still function is not getting called.. and also m not getting error in console related to this so this is making it harder to spot what actually is wrong over here

Comment: How about `$("#work_sanctioned_year").trigger("change")`?

Comment: didnt work @Anton

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script>
    function work_sanctioned(){
        console.log('onchange');
        var work_sanctioned_year = $("#work-sanctioned-year").val();
        alert(work_sanctioned_year);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'get_data.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {work_sanctioned_year:work_sanctioned_year},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    
                    success:function(response){
                    FusionCharts.ready();
                    }
        });
        FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var dataChart = new FusionCharts({
      "type": "overlappedBar2d",
      "renderAt": "chart-5",
      "width": '100%',
      "height": '400',
      "dataFormat": "json",
      "dataSource": {
        "chart": {
          "caption": "Major League Baseball - Season Rankings",
          "subCaption": "Teams in the Lead",
          "xAxisName": "Team",
          "yAxisName": "Position",
          "theme": "fusion",
          "showValues": "0"
        },
        "categories": [{
            "labelFontSize": "13",
          "category": [{
            "label": "Boston Red Sox"
          }, {
            "label": "New York Yankees"
          }, {
            "label": "Tampa Bay Rays"
          }, {
            "label": "Toronto Blue Jays"
          }, {
            "label": "Baltimore Orioles"
          }, {
            "label": "Cleveland Indians"
          }, {
            "label": "Detroit Tigers"
          }, {
            "label": "Minnesota Twins"
          }, {
            "label": "Chicago White Sox"
          }, {
            "label": "Kansas City Royals"
          }, {
            "label": "Cleveland Indians"
          }, {
            "label": "Detroit Tigers"
          }, {
            "label": "Minnesota Twins"
          }, {
            "label": "Chicago White Sox"
          }]
        }],
        "dataset": [{
          "seriesname": "Matches",
          "data": [{
            "value": parseInt(document.getElementById("work_sanctioned").value)-4650
          }, {
            "value": "84"
          }, {
            "value": "86"
          }, {
            "value": "86"
          }, {
            "value": "85"
          }, {
            "value": "85"
          }, {
            "value": "88"
          }, {
            "value": "83"
          }, {
            "value": "86"
          }, {
            "value": "86"
          }, {
            "value": "85"
          }, {
            "value": "88"
          }, {
            "value": "83"
          }, {
            "value": "86"
          }]
        }, {
          "seriesname": "Wins",
          "data": [{
            "value": "57"
          }, {
            "value": "54"
          }, {
            "value": "42"
          }, {
            "value": "39"
          }, {
            "value": "24"
          }, {
            "value": "46"
          }, {
            "value": "38"
          }, {
            "value": "35"
          }, {
            "value": "29"
          }, {
            "value": "25"
          }, {
            "value": "46"
          }, {
            "value": "38"
          }, {
            "value": "35"
          }, {
            "value": "29"
          }, {
            "value": "25"
          }]
        }]
      }
    })
    .render();
});

    }
</script>
```

and then called this on window.onload as well as on select property onchange

```
<select id="work-sanctioned-year" onChange="work_sanctioned()" style="max-width:40%;min-width:20%; margin:auto;">
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
        <option value="2020">2020</option>
        <option value="2021">2021</option>
        <option value="2022">2022</option>
        <option value="2023">2023</option>
    </select>
```

finally on window.onload

```
  <script>
    window.onload = function (){
    
      work_sanctioned();
    };
    
    </script>
```